Какой лимит вложенности списков в питоне?
Какой лимит вложенности списков в питоне? Или его вообще нет?

А каким образом вы видите там возможности ограничений? Есть ли какие-то ограничения на элементы списка?

Такой вопрос говорит скорее о серьёзных проблемах с идеологией программирования, чем о его существенности. Представляю себе как "весело" будет читать и исправлять программы, оперирующие многомерными списками всего-то через месяц. В Питоне достаточно ресурсов в этой части для реализации любых подобных фантазий.

rotabor незнаю, поэтому и спрашиваю.

Fox Fox, честно, мало что понял

Напишите простейшую программу с использованием списка. Попробуйте различные операции с ним.

Да, напишите программу, которая будет вкладывать список в список и при этом выводить вложенность. Как(если) упадет, возможно это и есть ограничение(или память закончилась)

a = []; a.append(a)

@andreymal Ну, это всего один уровень вложенности, хотя и бесконечный )  [[...]]

@CrazyElf как это у тебя одновременно "один" и "бесконечный" уровень вложенности?

В Python нет лимита вложенности для списка
Списки в Python, в отличии от массивов, хранят указатели (или ссылки) на другие объекты. Что и позволяет им быть любого уровня вложенности.

Наглядный пример разницы между списками или кортежами и массивами есть в книге Fluent Python от Luciano Ramalho:

В контейнерных последовательностях хранятся ссылки на объекты любого типа, когда как в плоских последовательностях - сами значения прямо в памяти, занятой последовательностью, а не как отдельные объекты Python.



... Закрашенные ячейки представляют заголовок объекта Python в памяти - пропорции не соблюдены. В кортеже хранится массив ссылок на элементы. Каждый элемент - отдельный объект Python, быть может, содержащий ссылки на другие объекты, скажем список из двух элементов. ...


Выходит, пока для массивов нужно дописывать отдельный функционал для каждого уровня вложенности, списки уже поддерживают вложенность любого уровня: достаточно лишь указать ссылку на другой список.
Самое простое доказательство - список который хранит ссылку на себя же:
self_pointing_list = []
self_pointing_list.append(self_pointing_list)

Проверить что это действительно список, первым элементом которого является он же, очень просто:
>>> self_pointing_list == self_pointing_list[0]
True
>>> self_pointing_list == self_pointing_list[0][0]
True


Единственное ограничение, с которым вы можете столкнутся, это ограничение памяти.
